# Why does this .every() function return true and then false?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

```
let nums = [-1, 50, 75, 200, 350, 525, 1000];

nums.every(function(num) {
  console.log(num < 0);
});
```

*true*

*=> false*

---

When I run this code in https://repl.it/@super8989/BraveFunctionalSale, this returns "true" then "=> false".

According to .every() description, the return value is "true if the callback function returns a truthy value for every array element; otherwise, false."

**Why does it show "true" and then "=> false"?**

---

Furthermore, when I change the array so that "- value" is in the middle of the array, it returns "false" then "=> false".

```
let nums = [1, 50, -75, 200, 350, 525, 1000];

nums.every(function(num) {
  console.log(num < 0);
});
```

*false*

*=> false*

https://repl.it/@super8989/CyberInterestingPhase

---

```
let nums = [-1, 50, 75, 200, 350, 525, 1000];

console.log(nums.every(num => num < 0));
```

*false*

*=> undefined*

But if I write it this way, this returns false then undefined.
https://repl.it/@super8989/MonstrousAjarDimension

---

I'm very confused... Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `return` inside .every, currently you are just logging num < 0 which is true for num[0] which is (-1 < 0), but false for num[1] which is (50 >= 0). And since you do not `return` is instantly exits the loop as this is considered `false`.

```js
let numsA = [-1, 50, 75, 200, 350, 525, 1000];
console.log("should return false, because 50 is >= 0");
console.log(numsA.every(function(num) {
  return (num < 0);
}));

let numsB = [1, 50, -75, 200, 350, 525, 1000];

console.log(numsB.every(function(num) {
  return (num < 0);
}));

let numsC = [-1, 50, 75, 200, 350, 525, 1000];

console.log(numsC.every(num => num < 0));

let numsD = [-5, 0, 5, 10, 15];
console.log("should return true because for each num in numsD, num %5 === 0");
console.log(numsD.every(num => {
  return num % 5 === 0
}));
//you can omit return with arrow function syntax, as this automatically returns the value within ()
console.log(numsD.every(num => (num % 5 === 0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Array.every method you must provide function that **returns** true or **false**. Function is being called for every one element in Array.
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/every

your function

```
nums.every(function(num) {
  console.log(num < 0);
});
```

returns undefined for every element (missing return statement).

```
var resutl = nums.every(function(num) {
  return (num < 0);
});
```

or in es-2017 syntax:

```
const resutl = nums.every(num => num < 0);
```